# Allow users to select without JS

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to develop a technique where I can allow users to select preset keywords from the database and add them to the form they are submitted. If I was using JS, I know I could just allow them to type in a keyword and it would pop up as a dynamic dropdown.

Without using JS, is there a clever technique to achieve this?

On the fly, how could I generate the keywords for the users to select, no matter how many they wanted.

I know it's a vague question but I believe there is a standard way of achieving this type of solution in a non JS environment.

Comment: except for printing out every keyword that exists and adding a checkbox to it i think it wouldn't be possible without any JS support

Comment: That was my thinking too. I was mainly just enquiring to see if anyone had invented a clever workaround for this type of problem. I think I may just have to alter the application to auto select keywords if there is no JS. Won't be as complete but it will only be a small amount of users!

Comment: Is there anyone without JavaScript support? 99% of nowadays web sites won't work at all.

Comment: he might want to go to some browsers of blackberry os versions < 5 :P , even there js is available. But turned off by default.

Comment: the only thing i really could considder a workout is klicking a link that opens a new page as `target="_blank"` in that page he klicks on every tag he wants to add and submits a microform that saves the selection php wise in the session and after closing the window he proceeds with his normal form. but that is really a bad workaround if you really have absolutely no js support...

Comment: Why should browsers having js support suffer this? or are you targeting only non js?

Comment: I'm purely attempting to design for non JS first and then add it for the vast majority who have it. Perhaps it's time to drop the support for non JS considering it affects the user experience so much!

Comment: @luke Just a side-note for supporting non-JS users, [2% of people](http://www.searchenginepeople.com/blog/stats-no-javascript.html) browse without Javascript enabled.  It is common to tell users that JS must be enabled for the site (web-application) to work. (Also used to notify people when cookies must be enabled for the site to work ^^)